# how to enclose a string in single-quotes using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a csv file and I need to enclose a string in a single-quotes on each line.

Example:

```
StartLine1 string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6 EndLine1
StartLine2 string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6 EndLine2
StartLine3 string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6 EndLine3
```

I used regular expression `([^,]+)` but appears that it is not giving me the correct results.

expected result:

```
StartLine1 'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6' EndLine1
StartLine2 'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6' EndLine2
StartLine3 'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6' EndLine1
```

Comment: Are `string1`, `string2`... single words or can they contain any character? Please, edit your question and give real  file.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: The strings are separated by comma and can contain any characters. I used string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6 as an example.

Comment: I am using the tool notepad+++

Comment: Could you show a real line? What is `StartLine1`? The exact word `StartLine1` a word that contains letters, digits, special char? Same question for `Endine` and `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with opening [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and using the following pattern:

```
(?<=[ ,])([^,\n]*?)(?=[ ,])
```

This is based on the sample you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out but it is not in one run
first I have to remove the starting string in the line (startline[x]) then the ending string (endline[x]).
then by using these regular expression to replace the strings that is separated by comma by a single-quotes
find: (\w[^,]+)
replace: '\1',
then add the single-quotes on each of the beginning of the line 
then put back the starting and end strings.

thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do those extra steps. Try with @Chillie 's answer